# Protocol static var used in method

Tags: swift, methods, static, protocols, swift-protocols

I have this **swift** code :

```
protocol Table {
    static var tableName: String { get }
}

class User: Table {
      internal static var tableName = "user"
}
```

I know would like to construct methods with `Table` protocol parameters.
Something like :

```
func doSomethingFrom(table: Table) {
  print(table.tableName)
}

doSomethingFrom(table: User) // prints "user"
```

Is there a way to achieve this simply ?

Comment: I assume `value` above was meant to be `tableName`?

Comment: @RobNapier indeed. I corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the syntax you're looking for. You need to pass the type itself by appending `.self`. This is to prevent mistakes (since talking about types directly is kind of rare, but easy to do by accident). And you need to take a parameter of the type itself rather than an instance of that type.

```
func doSomethingFrom(table: Table.Type) {
    print(table.tableName)
}

doSomethingFrom(table: User.self) // prints "user"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of tableName will be the same for all instances of User (because it is static) you can do:

```
func doSomethingFrom(table: Table) {
    print(User.tableName)
    // OR:
    print(type(of: table).tableName) 
}
```

Make sure though this is what you really want.